# ink dapp asking to sign transactions everytime i reload

Tags: ink, transactions, blockchain, polkadot-js-extension, database

so i am building a dapp with ink
it has messages to get data and put data
and on FE when i logged in with the polkadot-js extension wallet
everytime i reload the page it asks me to sign the transaction beacuase it makes a call to the contract messages to get and display the data
what will be the best solution for it,
i thought about implementing a cache mechanism or redis database to store data which already has been fetched and if the data is there no need to make a call to the message again.
but i don't know if there is any other way to getting rid of this may be from contract side ?

Comment: It is not possible to answer to the question if you don't provide more details, code snippets if possible. If you just reading from a smart contract signer wouldn't pop for that case.

Comment: You do not need to sign get messages from the frontend. Check that you do not have `&mut self` in your get message.

Comment: something is triggering this sign action, can you share your code or more information?